# My mod_rewrite rule is wrong, I can't seem to figure out how to write it to work for me

Tags: mod-rewrite

Here is my current .htaccess file:
(it is running on my personal WAMP server.  And Mod_Rewrite is enable on my server.)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /rdypages/

   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rdypages/index.php?company=$1&page=$2
</IfModule>
```

My /rdypages/index.php file is design to look for the following parameters in the quesystring:
company and page.  Here is an example address:

```
http://localhost:8888/rdypages/index.php?company=test&page=test.htm
```

and this is what I would like it to look like:

```
http://localhost:8888/rdypages/test/test.htm
```

What should my .htaccess file's RewriteRule say?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /rdypages/index.php?company=$1&page=$2
```

I have tested it and it works fine!